# Javascript cached on tomcat 8

Tags: javascript, macos, tomcat, caching

From time to time my updates to javascript file are not picked up by tomcat.  Even though the script file is deployed to the relevant directory, Chrome Developer console shows the older version of the script. The older version seems to be cached somewhere.

Stopping tomcat, removing work directory, restarting the server again  does not help. Even restarting the my mac does not make a difference.

Eventually, multiple cycles of shutting down tomcat, deleting work directory, and restarting server makes tomcat to pick up newer javascript file, but it does take a while.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

I am running tomcat 8.5.5 on Mac OS X 10.11.6 and Google Chrome.

Comment: Try `ctrl` + `F5` to clean browser cache. Even if tomcat serves the new file, the browser could have decided to cache it

Comment: Is this javascript file a static file, or are you generating it dynamically?

Comment: also, are you using any IDE to run tomcat, or are you running it directly? IntelliJ (but also others) has its own logic on how changes to files are passed on to the tomcat instance they are running.